Dynamic Code Loading issue on Android 14 devices
public void setPayment(PaymentResponse response){
        this.response = response;
        layout.findViewById(R.id.loader).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        layout.findViewById(R.id.payment_area).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(razorpay==null){
            //cause of error due to referencing from .aar file
            razorpay = new Razorpay(getActivity(),response.getPayment().getGatewayKey());
        }
        razorpay.setWebView(paymentLayout.findViewById(R.id.payments));
        //code continues
    }

For the above code snippet, I am facing the following error message on Android 14 devices:-
java.lang.SecurityException: writable dex file '/data/user/io.project.package.name/cache/.     ' is not allowed.
I have the razorpay.aar in my libs folder and also have included the following under dependencies in build.gradle:
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])
implementation files('libs/razorpay.aar')
However, I am facing this issue on Android 14 devices and haven't been able to figure how to mark it as read only, as required for Android 14.
Can anyone help me figure out exactly how to fix this issue? It runs smoothly on pre Android 14 devices. There is a more updated dependency version of the same .aar, and using that instead of the .aar seems to sort the issue on Android 14 devices, but it would require more refactoring and changes from server side as well. Hence, a solution fixing it at the application level, using the same .aar would be highly helpful and quicker for us to deploy as a hotfix.
Using Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1 to compile my build.

Have you tried removing the fileTree declaration? Just a complete guess, but you might want to check the aar is not being added twice

And are you testing a real device or an emulator?

I recommend that you edit your question and provide the complete stack trace associated with this exception.

@Blundell I have removed the fileTree declaration as well but no difference. And I have tested for the issue on multiple real Android 14 devices for replication

@CommonsWare the stacktrace originates from the above code point, before going into inbuilt library files etc. Not a useful stack trace, but will provide if it is required for clarity

As far as I know, Android 14 prevents app from loading writable DEX files to avoid security risks.
If you are loading .aar files of any ELF files in your app you can try set them to read-only by using setReadOnly() of File class.
val jar = File("DYNAMICALLY_LOADED_FILE.jar")
val os = FileOutputStream(jar)
os.use {
    // Set the file to read-only first to prevent race conditions
    jar.setReadOnly()
    // Then write the actual file content
}
val cl = PathClassLoader(jar, parentClassLoader)

Reference: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#safer-dynamic-code-loading

Where is this to be added in the Android code?

This should be added at the place where you want to load the ELF file
